# 'Fine' at the end of the song

Tags: sheet-music, terminology

In a lot of music sheets, I've seen that they mark the end of the song with 'Fine'

(example: http://www.jazzpla.net/H/Hassansdream.jpg)

What does 'Fine' mean? And why is it used to mark the end of a song?

Comment: I always like to think of it as a little congratulatory note waiting there at the end of the tune for me. Like the sheet music is telling me "Cheer up, fella, you did just fine!"

Comment: Your example is strange.  The 'fine' is unnecessary, but harmless.  But the lack of a Final bar line suggests that a further section, leading to a D.C. al Fine, may be missing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it means "the end" in italian. Remember that a lot of terms in classical music are in italian: rallentando, staccato, legato, etc.

Comment: I didn't know this one was italian, I thought it was the english word

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: Don't forget to pronounce it the Italian way - fee-nay - and not the English way.

Answer (score 10):

*Fine* pretty much means the end of a piece. In piece you used for your example the end is pretty obvious, but some pieces of music will end in the middle after a *D.S. al Fine*.

[image]

In this example you can see the end of the piece is not where it would usually be. *D.S. al Fine* itself means go the [Segno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dal_Segno) and play to the *Fine*. The *Fine* is used to say where the ending actually is.

Comment: Correct. Writing 'fine' at the end of the piece is really superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Italian for "finished".  standard notation text is usually in Italian per the standard ages ago.

So No more places to hop to.  End of song.

Comment: As other answers have said, it is Italian for "end". "Finished" would be the past participle 'finito'.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point or reason for putting 'fine' at the very *end* of a piece. It's obvious because of the double barline - and nothing following. However, the place it will be needed is where there is a DC or DS al Fine, which may well occur not at the last bar written, but at a bar somewhere else in the piece. Yes, there will be a double barline there, but in order to establish an absolute end, the word 'Fine' appears at that point.

Comment: There is definitely "some point of reason" if something like an orchestra part contains a *collection* of songs. It's often not very  obvious from a single instrumental part where the end of the song actually is, and "fine" might save the player trying to scramble a page turn which isn't necessary. There are enough typos in music engraved or hand copied "before computers" that a double bar line (or the lack of one) isn't necessarily conclusive evidence either way!

Answer (score 0):

"Fine" right at the end of the piece means two things: a) there is no ultimate reprise into the beginning/chorus: when the piece ends, it ends here.  b) it is explicitly not "attacca": the next movement is *not* commenced in one flourish.

Answer (score -4):

My understanding leads me to believe 'fine'(in the musical sense) means 'all stop' which is not at all superfluous, yes?

Comment: No, it means 'the end'.